# Add Identity Authentication to Identity Server Front end

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.1

I've created an Identity Server 4 project which runs our Identity server and I have created a front end to the project so we can maintain it.  The problem I am running into is it looks like I cannot have Identity Server middleware and use Identity Authentication in the same project.  Is there a way to get these two things to work?  I don't want to split this into two projects.

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
})
    // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources)
    .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
            b.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
        })
    // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
    .AddOperationalStore(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
            b.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

        // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
        options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
        // frequency in seconds to cleanup stale grants. 15 is useful during debugging
        options.TokenCleanupInterval = int.Parse(Configuration.GetSection("TokenCleanup").Value);
    })
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();


services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>().Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Saml/SingleSignOn";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.LogoutPath = "/Saml/SingleSignOn";
    options.Cookie.Expiration = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

services.AddTransient<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, CustomUserStore>();
services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<ApplicationRole>, CustomRoleStore>();

services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

Comment: From the [docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html): *It’s important when using ASP.NET Identity that IdentityServer be registered after ASP.NET Identity in the DI system because IdentityServer is overwriting some configuration from ASP.NET Identity.*

Comment: I did try that, but it just gives me this error: InvalidOperationException: sub claim is missing
IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerAuthenticationService.AssertRequiredClaims(ClaimsPrincipal principal) in IdentityServerAuthenticationService.cs, line 119.

It looks like it is still trying to do some Identity Server Authentication

Comment: Actually, there might be multiple things missing. If you haven't already, go through the docs I linked in my previous comment.

Comment: I built my project from those documents.